# Can Ultrasound and or Microwaves actually lock mass in place trapping it in standing wave nodes

Tags: gravity, modified-gravity

Ultrasound Standing waves trap small particles and manipulate their velocities and direction
and cause them to defy gravity. Source : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odJxJRAxdFU

Does current physics explain this phenomena ? And can we scale it up with higher energy node
trapping ?

Comment: Current physics does an excellent job describing this phenomena and other similar ones. You might Google for ion traps, Bose-Einstein Condensates, and other equally or more interesting things...

Comment: I think what you're looking for is called ponderomotive force. It works (google gives plenty examples) but is limited to fairly small objects AFAIK.